# Is there any governing body on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, tatooine

On Tatooine, is there any form of ruling body or law enforcement? Obviously the Republic has no control there, but is there any ruling government, or even a police force to keep things orderly?

Comment: The Hutts, and Imperial forces when they were looking for R2-D2 and ‘3PO

Comment: @Boolean Maybe the Hutts had some power, but the Empire didn't really control, or govern tatooine to my knowledge.

Comment: What time period are you asking about? Specific to the time shown in some particular movie, show, book, or game? They span *thousands* of years.

Comment: @TylerH  Let’s assumes for the moment that the OC is asking about the era in which the Skywalker Saga is set (episodes 1-9)

Comment: @Boolean That being a large assumption aside, Episodes I thru IX still spans some 68 years and, somewhat remarkably, includes no fewer than *four* galaxy-wide governmental authorities. Even just constrained to the movies, we see multiple different sets of authorities enforced.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Republic and Imperial Period

Per [StarWars.com](https://www.starwars.com/databank/tatooine), the Hutts run the cities and the starports as warlords. Outside of their own interests, they seem to have little or no desire to enforce anything.

> A harsh desert world orbiting twin suns in the galaxy’s Outer Rim,
> **Tatooine is a lawless place ruled by Hutt gangsters.** Many settlers
> scratch out a living on moisture farms, while spaceport cities such as
> Mos Eisley and Mos Espa serve as home base for smugglers, criminals,
> and other rogues. Tatooine’s many dangers include sandstorms, bands of
> savage Tusken Raiders, and carnivorous krayt dragons. The planet is
> also known for its dangerous Podraces, rampant gambling, and legalized
> slavery. Anakin Skywalker and Luke Skywalker both grew up on Tatooine,
> and Obi-Wan Kenobi spent years in hiding on this desolate world.

Out in the wilderness, it's the wild west. The [*Essential Atlas*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas) makes a passing reference to "*local councils*" but basically it's just moisture farmers protecting their own farms and banding together to periodically form lynch mobs to attack the Sandpeople.

As to law enforcement, we see in the canon comics that they nominally pay "protection" money to the Hutts but basically it's just a shakedown as the only protection they get is from Hutt reprisals for not paying.

### New Republic Period

With the decline in Hutt control after the death of Jabba, individual townships appear to have employed their own law enforcement in the form of sheriffs. Empowered by town leadership, these sheriffs have deep and wide latitude to 'keep the peace' by dispensing whatever justice they see fit.

> Cobb shrugs. “Oh, now. I’m no monster. No worse than your boss, that
> Weequay dung-muncher, Lorgan Movellan. I know his scam. I know all the
> scams. Afraid the Republic is back and gonna put their boot down on
> all the lowlifes and scum-lickers, the syndicates are trying to find
> new ways to appear legit. And with the Hutts fighting one another for
> control, bunch of these little quote-unquote mining companies are
> swooping in with brutes like your boss at the helm. A new age of
> mining barons. Won’t fly. **I’m here now. Me and others like me.
> Bringing the law to this lawless place.** And that starts with me
> shooting you and taking that armor out from under you.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Aftermath](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aftermath)</sup></sub>

Comment: How could slave trading be "legal" if the planet was "lawless".... That always bothered me. A minor quibble

Comment: @BBlake - It's legal in Hutt Space